# Openshift- git clone gives Permission denied (publickey,gssapi-keyex,gssapi-with-mic)

Tags: openshift, openshift-client-tools

I have created a new account with openshift online and have created my first app. I have `rhc` installed on my local machine. I setup ssh keys for the first time using `rhc setup -l loginname`
i used git clone to clone the remote repo and it worked fine. Then however after changes and tring to do a git push gave me the following error:

```
Permission denied (publickey,gssapi-keyex,gssapi-with-mic).
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.
Please make sure you have the correct access rights
```

I tried a couple of solutions provided in this forum like using `ssh-add` etc. but this did not work.I then made sure that all existing ssh keys under `.ssh` directory and from my openshift online account were deleted and all identities managed by ssh-agent were also deleted. I then launched `rhc setup` again This created the default ssh keys again and asked me if it could upload the public key which I selected yes to. 
However then it gives me the following error:

```
An SSH connection could not be established to appname-domain-name.rhcloud.com.
Your SSH configuration may not be correct, or the application may not be
responding. connection closed by remote host (Net::SSH::Disconnect)
```

Kindly help.

Comment: did you already solve this issue? I met kind of this with openshift origin 4.0.8 setup with puppet.

Comment: i have the same error

Answer (score 3):

I had the same problem while trying to clone from command line...

```
C:\> git clone GIT_URL  DIRECTORY_TO_CREATE
```

Finally, cloning from the GIT UI solved the problem. Go to menu item  All Programs --> GIT --> Git GUI and select "Clone existing repository".